# Send multiple flows of data using Python and Streamlit

Tags: python, database, firebase, multithreading, streamlit

I am trying to create a program, that reads a json message, copy that to a database, and a streamlit application controls the copy of the message, to create an artificial database by setting some parameters.

Hello!
I am trying to send new data to my firebase local DB.
This is my code:

```
import firebase_admin as firebase
from firebase_admin import db
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
import streamlit as st
import threading

#Global variable to control Firebase initialization
if 'firebase_initialized' not in st.session_state:
    config = {
        'databaseURL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=my-db'
    }
    firebase.initialize_app(None, config)
    st.session_state.firebase_initialized = True

id = '1'

# Function to add data to the Firebase database
def send_to_db(path, datos):
    ref = db.reference(f'{path}')    
    ref.set(datos) #Send data to DB

# Function to copy data to database in a thread
def copy_data(data, id, category, interval, run_event):
    while run_event.is_set():       
        times = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        oldTime = list(data['number'][category].keys())[0]
        path = f'/{id}/number/{category}/{times}'        
        send_to_db(path, data['number'][category][oldTime])        
        time.sleep(interval)

# Create flags to control thread execution
first_run_event = threading.Event()
second_run_event = threading.Event()
# Function to stop a thread
def stop_thread(run_event):
    run_event.clear()

with open("msg.json", "r") as file:
   json_message = file.read()
data = json.loads(json_message)

# First
st.header("First")
first_on_off = st.checkbox("Activar First")
first_interval = st.slider("Interval First (second)", min_value=1, max_value=60, value=5)
# Second
st.header("Second")
second_on_off = st.checkbox("Activar Second")
second_interval = st.slider("Interval Second (second)", min_value=1, max_value=60, value=5)

threads = []
run_first = first_on_off
run_second = second_on_off


start_sending = st.checkbox("Start Sending")
if start_sending:  
    if first_on_off:
        first_thread = threading.Thread(target=copy_data, args=(data, id, 'first', first_interval, first_run_event))
        threads.append(first_thread)
        first_run_event.set()  
        
    if second_on_off:
        second_thread = threading.Thread(target=copy_data, args=(data, id, 'second', second_interval, second_run_event))
        threads.append(second_thread)
        second_run_event.set()
    # Stop threads if checkboxes are disabled
    if not first_on_off:
        stop_thread(first_run_event)
    if not second_on_off:
        stop_thread(second_run_event)

elif not start_sending:
    for thread in threads:
        threads.remove(thread)
    # Stop threads if checkboxes are disabled
    if not first_on_off:
        stop_thread(first_run_event)
    if not second_on_off:
        stop_thread(second_run_event)

# Initialize all threads
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
# Waiting for all threads to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

I am trying to copy at each interval of time the data that is inside the msg.json file. An message example is:

```
{
    "number": {
        "first": {
            "2023-08-16T12:09:50": {
                "A": 1,
                "B": 2,
                "C": 3,
                "D": 4,
            }           
        },
        "second": {
            "2023-08-16T12:09:50": {
                "1": 100,
                "2": 200,

            }
        },
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the checkbox (so it is false) i don't want to send more data, it is sending. It does not matter if I click on the 'first', second or 'start-sending' checkbox. It always send data. Also, if I am sending data from the first thread, then I click on the Second checbox, it keeps sending the data, but it creates another thread, so first path, is running on 2 threads.

Any advice is great,
thank you